# DELL PowerEdge 2850 - How to change PEDC 4e/Di from RAID-0 to Raid-1?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, raid1, configuration

SERVER : PE 2850
RC: PEDC 4e/Di
Raid Config: Raid-0 (Current)
Disk: 2 X 300GB

I have very little in this server space, Recently I got a server PE 2850 and trying to 
change the RAID configuration from Raid-0 to Raid-1 but I dont have any option other than Raid-0.

Could someone help me in detail please.

regards,
Ananth Ramasamy Meenachi

Comment: Did you have OMSA installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can not migrate from a RAID0 to a RAID1 on the same disks and keeping the current volumes. However, you can destroy the volume and create a new one that is RAID1.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you don't have the option?  During boot when you press, what is it CTRL + R?, you can't destroy the 2 current disks and rebuild as RAID 1?  Where and how are you trying to build the RAID?